# login on bootstrap and java

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a login page with bootstrap using java language.
I share the following classes:
**loginBean.java:**

```js
    public String sign()
 {
     boolean loggedIn = false;  
        if(username != null  && username.equals("sarsoura") && password != null  && password.equals("ena")) 
        {  
         loggedIn = true;  
        } 
        else 
        {  
            loggedIn = false;  
        }  
      
        if(loggedIn==true) 
           return "List? faces-redirect=true";                   
        else
           return null;
    }
```

**loginPage.xhtml** (`First version`):

```html
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
 <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input onclick="#{loginBean.username}" />                                        
 </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <input value="#{loginBean.password}" /> 
    </div>
    <p:commandButton value="Login"   action="#{loginBean.sign}"  />                                                         
</h:panelGrid>
```

**loginPage.xhtml** (`Second version`):

```html
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
 <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" styleClass="form-control"/>                                      
 </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" /> 
    </div>
    <p:commandButton value="Login"   action="#{loginBean.sign}"  />                                                         
</h:panelGrid>
```

When I tried with the `Second version` of xhtml page, the login process works as well. However, after using the `First version`, that gives the null value of both username and password.

Have you please any idea about solving this issue: I mean I want to use `First version` that supports bootstrap instead of `Second version`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @NikolasCharalambidis, I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804633/how-can-i-login-using-bootstrap that help me solving this issue. I tried with value instead of onclick, but that the problem persists.